# how to find the sum for an array of struct type?

Tags: google-bigquery

how to find the sum of 2015th first quarterly?

```
with table1 as(
select [struct("jan" as month,2000 as quantity_sold),("feb",5000),("mar",3000)] as Q1_2015,
 [struct("jan" as month,2050 as quantity_sold),("feb",5100),("mar",3200)]as Q1_2016,
 [struct("jan" as month,3000 as quantity_sold),("feb",4000),("mar",3800)]as Q1_2017)
 ,
table2 as(
select(array(select x from unnest(Q1_2015)x order by quantity_sold desc))as tab2_1
from table1)

select tab2_1, sum(tab2_1.quantity_sold)   from table2;
```

I have the following error

```
Error: Cannot access field quantity_sold on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<month STRING, quantity_sold INT64>> at [10:19]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - without `GROUP BY` your final `SELECT` will not work anyway - and will fail with something as below

```
Error: SELECT list expression references column tab2_1 which is neither grouped nor aggregated
```

Meantime, to fix your current issue with below error:

```
Error: Cannot access field quantity_sold on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<month STRING, quantity_sold INT64>> at [10:19]
```

you should use something like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS(
  SELECT 
    [STRUCT("jan" AS month,2000 AS quantity_sold),("feb",5000),("mar",3000)] AS Q1_2015,
    [STRUCT("jan" AS month,2050 AS quantity_sold),("feb",5100),("mar",3200)]AS Q1_2016,
    [STRUCT("jan" AS month,3000 AS quantity_sold),("feb",4000),("mar",3800)]AS Q1_2017
), table2 AS(
SELECT
  (ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(Q1_2015) x ORDER BY quantity_sold DESC)) AS tab2_1
  FROM table1
)
SELECT SUM(tab2_1[OFFSET(0)].quantity_sold)   
FROM table2
```

Above just addresses you issue with error you presented in question - the rest of logic is exactly as it is in your question and I don't think result is what you expected  - most likely it is just start of your "journey"

Anyway - to produce the sum of three months  - use below instead

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS(
  SELECT 
    [STRUCT("jan" AS month,2000 AS quantity_sold),("feb",5000),("mar",3000)] AS Q1_2015,
    [STRUCT("jan" AS month,2050 AS quantity_sold),("feb",5100),("mar",3200)]AS Q1_2016,
    [STRUCT("jan" AS month,3000 AS quantity_sold),("feb",4000),("mar",3800)]AS Q1_2017
), table2 AS(
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(quantity_sold) FROM UNNEST(Q1_2015)) AS total_sold
  FROM table1
)
SELECT total_sold   
FROM table2
```

I consider this particular question is answered - please post any new questions as "New Questions"

Comment: I get wrong answer.                                                                                
  Row  f0_                                                                                                            
  1       5000                                                                                                      
   It is not 5000 but 10000 is the correct answer.

Comment: what do you mean  - please clarify

Comment: i just focused on "fixing" error you faced in your question  - and left everything else totally as it is in your initial query - as I mentioned - it is `most likely is just start of your "journey"` . Check update I added to my answer :o) feel free to accept and if any more questions - post the new one!